# Azure storage metrics data

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am trying to implement azure storage metrics code in my role but i am checking if there is easy way to get azure storage metric data about my files usage. my code is stable and i do not want to change code again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if you already have Windows Azure role running, then you don't need to make any changes to your code and you still can get Windows Azure Blob storage Metrics data.

I have written a blog about it last time as [Collecting Windows Azure Storage REST API level metrics data without a single line of programming, just by using tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/10/11/collecting-windows-azure-storage-rest-api-level-metrics-data-without-a-single-line-of-programming-just-by-using-tools.aspx)

Please try above and see if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Storage analytics is disabled by default, so any operations against your storage up til now has *not* been logged for analysis.

You may choose to enable analytics at any time, for both logging (detailed access information for every single object) and metrics (hourly rollups). Further, you may choose which specific storage service to track (blobs, tables, queues) and which operations to track (read, write, delete). Once analytics are enabled, you may access the resulting analytics data from any app (as long as you have the storage account name + key).

Persistent Systems just published a [blog post](http://blog.persistentsys.com/index.php/2012/05/18/metering-resource-usage-for-multiple-tenants-using-storage-analytics/#) on enabling storage analytics for Java apps. The same principles may be applied to a .net app (and the sdk's are very similar).

Additionally, Full Scale 180 published a [sample app](http://azurestorexray.codeplex.com/) encapsulating storage analytics (based on REST API, as it was written before SDK v1.6 came out).